# when is the /etc/hosts file loaded?

Tags: dns, hosts

I'm trying to configure some virtual hosts and I'm quite confused as to when this file is loaded.

At what point is `/private/etc/hosts` loaded? When logging in? At every DNS call? When Mac OS restarts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [hosts(5) manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/hosts.5.html) provides some insight into how `/etc/hosts` is used.

The file is used by `mDNSResponder` and, given your question, I suspect you want to see edits to `/etc/hosts` reflected in your DNS look-ups.

After each edit of `/etc/hosts` reset the `mDNSResponder` cache using this Apple technical note, [OS X: How to reset the DNS cache](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5343):

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

The note explains when you might need to do this:

> **When you might want to do this**
>
> OS X keeps a local cache of resolved DNS queries for a time defined by
>   the DNS server, but sometimes it may be necessary to reset the cache
>   immediately and re-query a DNS server. For example, you might do this
>   after an entry on the server is changed or a new entry is added.

Answer (score 2):

Usually changes to `/etc/hosts` are updated automatically within a few seconds, and I haven't needed to reset the DNS cache manually.

If you try to run `sudo opensnoop|grep /etc/hosts` and edit `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hosts` is read by `mDNSResponder` almost immediately after you save it.

Comment: I suspect in later versions of OS X, Apple started actively watching the `hosts` file for changes using the kqueue mechanism.